# How to accept decimal as input inside soldity function

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to accept a decimal number as input inside solidity function but I am unable to do so.
I know decimal number doesn't work in solidity but is there any way to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no `decimal` type in solidity, but you can scale your numbers (for instance multiply numbers in 10^3) and treat them as `int` in your contract.